# Ramda, filter with or condition

Tags: ramda.js

```
let arr = [
  {
    name: 'Anna',
    q: {
      name: 'Jane'
    }
  }
];

const getName = R.prop('name');
const getQname = R.path(['q','name']);
```

A filter where any of these two functions passes.

Something like:

```
export const filterByName = (name) => 
R.filter(
  R.or(
   R.propEq(getName, name),
   R.propEq(getQname, name)
  )
)
```

Not working. How can I combine these two functions in a R.filter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use R.either with R.propEq for the `name` and R.pathEq from `q.name`:

```js
const filterByName = (name) =>
  R.filter(
    R.either(
      R.propEq('name', name),
      R.pathEq(['q', 'name'], name)
    )
  )

const arr = [{"name":"Anna","q":{"name":"Jane"}},{"name":"Smite","q":{"name":"Jane"}},{"name":"Another","q":{"name":"One"}}];

console.log(filterByName('Anna')(arr))
console.log(filterByName('Jane')(arr))
console.log(filterByName('XXX')(arr))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```

If you want to use an external function to extract the values, you can use R.pipe. Extract all property values with R.juxt, and then use R.any with  R.equal to check for equality.

```js
const getName = R.prop('name');
const getQname = R.path(['q','name']);

const filterByName = (name) =>
  R.filter(
    R.pipe(
      R.juxt([getName, getQname]), // get all names
      R.any(R.equals(name)) // check if any of the equals to name
    )
  )

const arr = [{"name":"Anna","q":{"name":"Jane"}},{"name":"Smite","q":{"name":"Jane"}},{"name":"Another","q":{"name":"One"}}];

console.log(filterByName('Anna')(arr))
console.log(filterByName('Jane')(arr))
console.log(filterByName('XXX')(arr))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```

Comment: Good catch! I didn't see the issue with the path in OP original attempt. I updated my answer but credits to you.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `either` as it works with functions:

```js
export const filterByName = (name) => 
  R.filter(R.either(
   R.propEq('name', name),
   R.pathEq(['q', 'name'], name)));
```

or

```js
const nameIs = R.propEq('name');
const qNameIs = R.pathEq(['q','name']);

export const filterByName = (name) => 
  R.filter(R.either(nameIs(name), qNameIs(name)));
```

Comment: What if I want to use my previous functions. The getName, and getQname. In my example these are simple but in my code I have more complex extractions. Would like to reuse these functions.

Comment: What function would I use if I had more than 2 conditions?

Comment: @Joe You'd probably want to look at [`anyPass`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#anyPass)

Comment: Ah ok. Thx. Difficult to know exactly what function to use. There's so many of them.

Answer (score 0):

You could also write this in a point free style:

```js
const nameIs = R.converge(R.or, [
  R.pathEq(['name']),
  R.pathEq(['q', 'name']),
]);

const onlyAnna = R.filter(nameIs('Anna'));
const onlyGiuseppe = R.filter(nameIs('Giuseppe'));

const data = [
  { name: 'Anna', q: { name: 'Jane' } },
  { name: 'Mark', q: { name: 'Mark' } },
  { name: 'Giuseppe', q: { name: 'Hitmands' } },
];

console.log('Anna', onlyAnna(data));
console.log('Giuseppe', onlyGiuseppe(data));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```